# Django Using oembed to convert url to embed url(VIMEO)

Tags: django, vimeo, vimeo-api, django-oembed

I try to convert video url to embed url using oEmbed, but:

[image]

When I `print(video_url_api_data)` it keeps returning `<Response [404]>`

I checked it with using url in google: https://vimeo.com/api/oembed.json?url=https://vimeo.com/570924262

What did I doing wrong in my code? And what do I have to put in the status part?

This status part:

```
vimeo_authorization_url = v.auth_url(
                ['private'],
                'http://127.0.0.1:8000/',
                1 #status
            )
```

I put 1 for random and it works.

```
import json, vimeo, requests
    
class article_upload(View):
     def post(self ,request, *args, **kwargs):    
            v = vimeo.VimeoClient(
                token='****',
                key='****',
                secret='****'
            )
            file_data = request.FILES["file_data"]
            path = file_data.temporary_file_path()
            try:
                vimeo_authorization_url = v.auth_url(
                    ['private'],
                    'http://127.0.0.1:8000/',
                    1 #status
                )
                video_uri = v.upload(path, data={'name': '비디오 제목', 'description': '설명'})
                video_data = v.get(video_uri + '?fields=link').json()
                video_url = video_data['link']
                params={"url": video_url}
                video_url_api_data = requests.get('https://vimeo.com/api/oembed.json', params=params)
                
                
                return render(request, 'account/myvideopage.html', {context(I made it)})
    
            except vimeo.exceptions.VideoUploadFailure as e:
                print("ohohohohohoh...vimeo error")
    
            finally:
                file_data.close()  # Theoretically this should remove the file
                if os.path.exists(path):
                    os.unlink(path)  # But this will do it, barring permissions
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved it before! The problem was... the delay time!

here ... I upload video.. of which size is at least 10MB

```
video_uri = v.upload(path, data={'name': '비디오 제목', 'descriptio...
```

and before i finish upload it I request information by using api...

```
 video_url_api_data = requests.get('https://vimeo.com/api/oem...
```